# Difference between Hadoop cgroups and schedulers

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to understand cgroups in Hadoop, but couldn't get it completely. How different are they from schedulers which allocate resources to each queues based on configured rules? My understanding is that Schedulers seems to be more of memory related where as groups are to do with CPU. Is my understanding correct? I'm sure I am missing something here.

Any expert guidance please.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Hadoop 2 (YARN) schedulers are responsible for assigning container for the execution of the task. Each of the container are assigned with fixed memory to use during the execution. When a task try to use more memory than assigned, `NodeManager` will kill the task.

But what if the task is using all the CPU available in the node. In that case, others will not be able to make any progress. So to control the CPU usages of the container, you can configure `CGroup` to the task. This is feature provide by linux kernel.

You can read more on at the following resources:
[Managing Multiple Resources in Hadoop 2 with YARN](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/12/managing-multiple-resources-in-hadoop-2-with-yarn/)
[Using YARN with Cgroups](http://riccomini.name/posts/hadoop/2013-06-14-yarn-with-cgroups/)